# The same model but not the same query params could not set in one route by ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My ember version:

```
---------------------------
 Ember             : 2.10.2
 Ember Data        : 2.10.0
 jQuery            : 2.2.4
 Ember Simple Auth : 1.1.0
 Model Fragments   : 2.3.2
---------------------------
```

My route code like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model() {
    return RSVP.hash({
      orderTransactionTypes: this.store.query('transactionType', {
        filter: {
          category: 'order_category'
        }
      }),
      otherTransactionTypes: this.store.query('transactionType', {
        filter: {
          category: 'transaction_category'
        }
      })
    });
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
})
```

In `RSVP.hash` all data come from `transactionType`, but they have not same query params. I use this way set model will have a problem is `model. orderTransactionTypes` and `model.otherTransactionTypes` become same data.

Whey this problem is happened? And how can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You need to verify the response for `orderTransactionTypes` and  `otherTransactionTypes` for both. and check overriding any of the methods like `urlForQuery` and `normalizeResponse`.  your route code looks perfect. Side Note: By default `setupController` will set model property in controller.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem you are having?

Comment: Kumkanillam said right. I think is my problem. @Steve H . Thanks.